# JenkinsFile: How to set env.variable at runtime from a script?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a JenkinsFile to pull a secret from Jenkins and use it further by setting it up as an environment variable. Below is my code snippet. How to set `env.K8S_CREDENTIALS_ID_STG` value from a script or a hardcoded value for starting point and pass it Kubernetes functions to deploy what Kubernetes is doing? I want to remove the dependency of storing secrets in Jenkins or Kubernetes. We have our own credential management from where we fetch secrets over API calls at runtime.

```
steps {
    script {
        env.K8S_CREDENTIALS_ID_STG = 'ece-prm-agents-stg-token'
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ece_auto', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USER', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASS')]){
            statusCheck('pending', 'deploy to stg')
            try {
                glKubernetesDeleteBasic credentials: "$env.K8S_CREDENTIALS_ID_STG",cluster: "k8s-nonprod-ctc-aci.optum.com",namespace: "ece-prm-stg", yaml: "ece-kinds/k8/ece-prm-k8-depl-stg.yaml", env: "Dev", isProduction: false
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                echo "${e}"
            }
            try{
                glKubernetesCreateBasic credentials: "$env.K8S_CREDENTIALS_ID_STG",cluster: "k8s-nonprod-ctc-aci.optum.com",namespace: "ece-prm-stg", yaml: "ece-kinds/k8/ece-prm-k8-depl-stg.yaml", env: "Dev", isProduction: false
                statusCheck('success', 'deploy to stg')
            } catch (Exception ex){
                statusCheck('failure', 'deploy to stg')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove the dependency of having to store secrets in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

I would write a Shared Library Step that accepts the name of the credential to get, then calls out to your Credentials API and returns the credential back to the pipeline

so something like

```
steps {
  script {
    env.K8S_CREDENTIALS_ID_STG = getMyCredentials('ece-prm-agents-stg-token')
```

More info on Shared Libraries can be found here if you haven't used them before
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Of course if the API is Authd then you will have the secret zero problem but I would suggest that one being sensible to store in Jenkins